# what did these matlab code do to matrix covpatt

Tags: matlab, matrix

```
covpatt1=covpatt;

covpatt(all(~covpatt1,2),:)=[];

covpatt(:,all(~covpatt1,1))=[];
```

I tried using these code, covpatt is a matrix, but I don't know what did these code do to covpatt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets take it step-by-step.

`~covpatt1` matrix indicates which elements in the `covpatt1` matrix are zero. `all(X,2)` indicates which of the rows of matrix `X` has all non-zero elements. Therefore, `all(~covpatt1,2)` indicates which of the rows of `covpatt1` have all zeros. Finally, `covpatt(all(~covpatt1,2),:)=[];` replaces such rows consisting of all zeros by an empty matrix. That is basically deletion of those rows.

Similarly, for the second statement, `covpatt(:,all(~covpatt1,1))=[];`, it replaces columns which contains all zeros by an empty matrix i.e. removes those columns.

I think this example clearly illustrates the purpose of the above code:

```
covpatt=[1 0 2;0 0 0;-3 0 2]

covpatt =

 1     0     2
 0     0     0
-3     0     2

%your code segment

covpatt1=covpatt;
covpatt(all(~covpatt1,2),:)=[];
covpatt(:,all(~covpatt1,1))=[];

%result

covpatt =

 1     2
-3     2
```